# Scroll to the top relative to clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I have a list of `div` and I'd like that, when I click on one of them, the page scrolls until the clicked element is on the top of the view. 
My code: http://jsfiddle.net/rcxnogmx/

Js code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#click").click(function (){
        $('html, body').scrollTop( $(this).offset().top );
    });
});
```

I've tried scrollTop -> this, but it doesn't work

Comment: **`ID`'s must be unique.**

Comment: There is no `#click` element..

Comment: _the page scrolls until the clicked element is on the top of the view_  <- This is not clear.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/rcxnogmx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Yes, id should be unique for each element.

Rather than by ID, you can do it by class.
You can give class name to DIV "scrolling".

element that has "scrolling" class click event scrolltop to its' top offset

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".scrolling").click(function (){
        $('html, body').scrollTop( $(this).offset().top );
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcxnogmx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without javascript. Standard HTML anchors allow you to scroll an element with a specific id to the top. The scrolled element can be the anchor itself:

```
<a id="this-anchor" href="#this-anchor">jump here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link

http://jsfiddle.net/rcxnogmx/2/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("div").click(function (){
        $('html, body').scrollTop( $(this).offset().top );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'click' id does not exist in your html.